# button apply change doesn''t exist

Tags: android-studio

I'm new in android developpement.

I want to use the button aplly change, but this button is not present.

Current result :
[current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMOXv.png)

Expected result : 
[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1Oke.png)

Answer (score 0):

Click Run on the menu and then Edit Configurations... then click on Android Application on the left and click the + button. Choose Android Application from the pop-up menu. Then pick the module (its normally app or something like that). Then click apply and ok.

If you have more errors after that, try to re-import the project in Android Studio